# Will java machine code be the same on the same hardware?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode

I know that java source code will be compiled to bytecode, and JVM will interpret that bytecode and translates it into native machine code for the underlying platform.

But i would like to know if i have a x86 machine, no matter which OS i choose to install, will the machine code which translated by the platform dependent JVM be the same?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**TL;DR** - No it won't.

The native code generated by the JIT compiler from identical bytecodes, by an identical Java release, and on the same OS *could still be different*.

- The generated code *could* depend on the physical hardware that the JVM is running on; e.g. the number of cores, the chipset, etcetera.
- The generated code *could* even depend on the inputs to the program.  Before JIT compiling, the JVM uses a bytecode interpreter to run the code.  This *self-profiling* gathers stats about branch probabilities, etcetera.  These stats are used by the JIT optimizer.  Since the code paths taken while running a program can depend on program inputs, different runs of the same program on the same machine may end up with the JIT compiler generating different native code.
- Since non-deterministic behavior during the JVM warmup can affect the stats gathered during self-profiling, it is even possible for the generated code to differ between runs of identical code on identical platforms with identical inputs.

That's the nice thing about HotSpot JIT compilation.  It adapts to the environment, and what the application does.  But this can be a problem if your primary goal is to get *reproducible* native code and *reproducible* performance characteristics.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Will the generated code depend on the usage rate of the CPU, memory, etc? For example, the machine code which generated when the system is busy will be different from that when the system is idle. (using the identical hardware, OS, java release)

Comment: The self-profiling, e.g. to determine the hot spots, depends on the timing that can be subtle in some scenarios. So I’d not only say, that the generated code may change with the system load, it may even differ spuriously, without an obvious cause. Some compilation tasks run concurrently to the application threads (and other processes on the same machine), so their progress can be influenced by them, which in turn influences later compilation decisions (e.g. a slowdown in one task may make more meta information available for the next one).

Comment: There are typically more than one JIT compiler threads (at least, one C1 and one C2), and they work in background. Since timings are not determenistic, the compilation order may differ, and so may the generated code (as it depends on many factors, including the runtime profile, the compilation history, the length of compilation queues etc.) I've seen many times, especially on microbenchmarks, that the generated code differs from run to run, even without notable change in the system load.

Answer (score 0):

With the same OS, it will be probably the same or very similar. However, different OSes implement most things in a really different way. For example, for most functions, you use *interrupts* in Linux, and WINAPI calls in Windows. This assembly code writes into a file on Linux:

```
mov eax, 4 ; system call for write
mov ebx, file_descriptor ; file descriptor
mov ecx, string ; data to write
mov edx, string_len ; data length
int 80h ; invoke interrupt
```

And this does the same on Windows:

```
push 0 
push 0
push string_len
push string
push hFile ; file handle
call _WriteFile@20
```

Even though the Java libraries use their own abstractions, in the end of the day, calls like this are used to communicate with the system. The native code generated by anything is usually not just hardware-dependent, but also OS-dependent. An exception would be some kind of program which does not interface with the OS in any way (adds two numbers, but never prints out anything), which is kind of useless.

Comment: I don't think this is relevant to the Question asked.  The JIT compiler doesn't generate code that performs the kind of calls you are talking about.  The assembly code you have show us would be part of the OS specific executable, or a native code library.  The cde would be created ahead of time, not at runtime.